# Accessing the contents of a generic collection passed to a method using keyword super with the help of enhanced for statement

Tags: java, generics

Here is my Java Code:

```
    package com.Pramithas.Project;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    abstract class Animal{
        public abstract void check();
    }

    class Dog extends Animal{
        public void check(){
            System.out.println("From inside Dog");
        }
    }

     public class AnimalDoctor {

        public void checkAnimals(List<? super Dog>animals){
            animals.add(new Dog());

            for(Animal a:animals){
                // Here is the problem. I also tried (Dog d:animals),
                //but it did not work either. 
            }
        }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

             List<Animal>myList=new ArrayList<Animal>();
             myList.add(new Dog());
             myList.add(new Dog());
             new AnimalDoctor().checkAnimals(myList);
        }
    }
```

Inside the method checkAnimals() I am trying to access the contents of the list `animals` using `enhanced for statement`. But having the problem. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list could contain Objects, Animals and Dogs, so you would need to write `for(Object o : animals)`

Alternative you could define your list as `List<? extends Animal>`, which would make sure only Animals are in your list.

**? super X** means "everything that is a superclass of X (including X itself)"

**? extends X** means "everything that extends X (including X itself"

Answer (score 1):

When you do `<? super Dog>`, it tells the compiler to accept any super type of `Dog` **up till `Object`** and any Interfaces.

And it is meant to be used only as a **Consumer**, read about [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2775450).

So, ideally you shouldn't be trying to read from a `<? super X>` object, only **add** values to that.

But if you still want to read, you need to assign it as an `Object`.

```
for(Object a3:animals){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you've defined your list (`List<? super Dog>`) denotes a list, where [you can add elements to, but cannot get elements from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

From what I can see, the `checkAnimals()` method is interested in both reading from and writing to the list, so you have to change it to:

```
public void checkAnimals(List<Animal> animals){
    animals.add(new Dog());

    for(Animal a : animals){

    }
}
```

Comment: I did it as a programming exercise. Thanks for your guidance though